# android arraylist cannot be applied

Tags: android

Hello I would like to know how to add information on an array list, for example I return the computer information and add it to the list but I would like to add in the list the information of the system of operation of Computers my os page, I do not see how to do it. I tried several ways but I had the error : cannot be applied

My code from my computer list:

```
    public static ArrayList<ordinateur>detail = new ArrayList<>();

    private void chargerJeuDessaie()
        {
            progressDialog = progressDialog.show(this,"Affichage du matériel : ordinateur","Telechargement en cours");
            MonAsyncTaskHttp monAsyncTaskHttp = new MonAsyncTaskHttp() {

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                    super.onPostExecute(o);
                    Mat_asso_ord.detail.clear();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(o.toString(

));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ordinateur ord = ordinateur.factoryOrdi(jsonObject);
                        Mat_asso_ord.detail.add(ord);

                        rafraichirListView();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
        monAsyncTaskHttp.execute("requete=getLesecoleetord&etab="+ search_ville.etabSELECT.getId());
    }

    public void rafraichirListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<ordinateur> ordinateuradapter = new ArrayAdapter<ordinateur>(Mat_asso_ord.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, detail);
        lv.setAdapter(ordinateuradapter);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the ArrayList in your code? What is the complete error message?

Comment: What class is this in?

Comment: The first problem is that you should not declare the ArrayList as static.

Comment: We also need the entire error message in English as well as the line which causes it.